# Where do attached properties fit in a class diagram?

Tags: .net, wpf, uml, dependency-properties, class-diagram

What is the most appropriate way to represent attached properties in a UML diagram or an almost-uml diagram like the VS2008 class diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UML it'll be quoted tag before the member. Something conventional, like this:

```
"attached" Align: ElementAlign
```